# Border radius breaks while running CSS animation in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, border-radius

Here is the CSS animation I am playing:

```css
#mydiv{
  width: 700px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50px;
}

#mydiv:before{
  content: "";
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 174, 0);
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: loading 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes loading{
  from{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  to{
    transform: translateX(500%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
</div>
```

It should show the yellow part with rounded edges moving inside the black div from left to right. But here is how I am seeing it in my Google Chrome browser:

[image: gif]

You can clearly notice that the right side of the yellow part isn't round throughout the whole animation, it's breaking. I tested this animation in Firefox and Edge in my pc and also on Chrome of another pc and it was showing without any bug in those browsers. I am facing this problem in Chrome of my pc only. When I tried to take a screenshot of the broken border-radius of the yellow part, it was showing correctly in the screenshot. Then I recorded my screen, and when I played the recorded video, the animation was looking bugless there too, I don't know why. So, I had to record this in my mobile, convert it into a gif and post it here.

What could be the reason for this behaviour of my Google Chrome? What is the fix for this?

**UPD1**: I was investigating this issue using chrome dev tools, and noticed that the bug goes away instantly when I enable [Paint Flashing](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/simplify-paint-complexity-and-reduce-paint-areas), and it appears again if I disable it.

**UPD2**: The bug also goes away when I inspect anything of that page in chrome dev tools, it appears again when I stop inspecting.

Comment: You have found a really cool bug! However I do not replicate it on Chrome 85.0.4183.121 MacOS 10.14.6... good luck

Comment: Still no luck, I think I will just to move on.

Comment: Have you tried forcing it to render in its own context? Like adding translateZ(0)

Comment: Tried after reading your comment, it didn't help.

Comment: It is cut off - I can't reproduce this bug, test with other values of width's - you have overflow: hidden - I think yellow ball is overflowing

Comment: It's not overflowing in the middle. And I have tested with other values, it always get cut off, regardless of the width, the amount of cut off varies, but I couldn't figure out any pattern of that.

Comment: Pleas check page https://validator.w3.org/unicorn/ if is green, test `border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px` for stupid user-agent, and `border-radius: 40%` (not sure how much % for this shape)  check also updates for the browser... weird